# remove CSP header from webview in chromeApp

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app, webrequest

I'm trying to remove the CSP header from specific website.

The problem is that i cant get the first request of the webview.

The (webRequest API) is only available after the webview is started to load, and I cant get the first request.

And the code below dose not work since it starts to listen to late

** The wierd part is that it works if the devtools of the webview is open :0

```
previewWebview.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
  var HEADERS_TO_STRIP_LOWERCASE = [
        'content-security-policy',
        'content-security-policy-report-only'
    ];
    previewWebview.request.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
        function (details) {

            return {
                responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders.filter(function (header) {
                    return HEADERS_TO_STRIP_LOWERCASE.indexOf(header.name.toLowerCase()) === -1;
                })
            };
        }, {
            urls: ["<all_urls>"]
        }, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it work right from the beginning (i.e. from the first load), you'd need the [webview declarative webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-WebRequestEventInterface).

```
  var w1 = document.createElement('webview');
  var headerRemoveRule = {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.webViewRequest.RequestMatcher()
    ],
    actions: [
      new chrome.webViewRequest.RemoveResponseHeader({
        name: 'x-robots-tag'
      })
    ]
  };

  // declarative WebRequest API, call before loading webview.
  w1.request.onRequest.addRules([headerRemoveRule]);
  w1.src = 'https://jsbin.com/piwakil';
  document.body.appendChild(w1);
```

Comment: This changes nothing, the request property still not exist until the first request.

Comment: What version of chrome are you running? On 53.0.2785.113, I definitely see request property on a webview element right after creating it (and not loading it).

Comment: Im using 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit) and notice im talking about chromeApp

Comment: You need to wait unit the app 'document' is ready, to get the 'request' API
And this method is also not capturing the first request